# Transfer file to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have to files range in size between 20 GB to 90 GB. The files are on my Windows server at Azure Virtual Machine. I need to transfer these files to my Azure Storage account to use it later. The total files sizes about 550 GB. Will Azure Storage Explorer do the job, or there are a better solution? My Azure account is a BizSpark one with 150 $ limit, shall I remove the limit before transferring the files to the storage account?
Any other advice?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to use Azure Storage Explorer but you'll probably have more luck using the [AzCopy](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) tool, it's the recommended method for transferring large file to storage. Take a look at the "[Copy a Single Blob](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/#_copy-a-single-blob)" section for an example of uploading a file to a storage account.

Regarding the billing limits - you shouldn't need to but it depends on what else you have on your subscription, type of storage etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. So, the BizSpark subscription will allow to store 550 GB in the account within the free monthly limit?

Comment: Probably. 550gb will cost up to $32 per month depending on the level of redundancy you want, but it depends on what else is on your subscription. Take a look at the pricing calculator to be sure: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/?scenario=data-management

Comment: @AdamFlanagan Hello Adam, i have almost the same need, i want to transfert files from ftp server to storage or blob after doing transformation, i started by using the logic app trigger "onAddFile" and i want to figure out what should i trigger just after to make this transformation possible (web job, azure function or something else) ? can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

There is a open source blog transfer utility available. You can try that.

Here is the link for that.

https://blobtransferutility.codeplex.com/

It also provides facility to upload things in batched.

Regarding billing it totally depends on your subscription.